# Monitoring download status of web worker script

Tags: html, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

Consider having a Web Worker of a size or customers with slow internet connections so downloading may take a while. During this time, we would like to be able to see how much the client already downloaded and how much is still outstanding. What is the *gold standard* to achieve it? Does the Web Worker interface provide any information about that?

I could imagine doing something similar to

1. Parent site starts an intermediate script as Web Worker:
   `new Worker( 'intermediateWorker.js' );` and tells it, which the actual worker script is.
2. Intermediate script downloads the actual worker utilizing an XHR
3. Intermediate script monitors progress through the XHR's `progress` event and `postMessage`s them to its parent site
4. When the XHR is complete, it uses `eval()` to execute the code and notifies its parent site after it evaluated the code and finally unsubscribes itself from all event listeners.
5. Now communication between the parent site and actual worker script can take place as if there has never been a intermediate script.

However, for good reasons, I'd like to avoid eval and overly complicated intermediate scripts:

- Overhead for downloading an additional script
- Maintenance of an additional script
- Use of eval
- Cross-origin-request difficulties, including errors on `file:` protocol in IE, CDN hosting the huge code files etc.

Comment: What size in kilobytes would be a typical ww ? Its just js source so should download in no time

Comment: @ScottStensland In this particular case, I have compiled an Audio encoder with Emscripten; the result is a 1.1 MiB chunk of JS. GZIP compressed, it might be smaller but on a slow mobile connection, for example still needs a while to download. And I guess that downloading huge code libraries for client side processing will evolve and become more popular in future when, for example, significant upload bandwidth can be saved this way.